# jQuery not selecting id containing "<" angular bracket?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not able to select checkbox which has `id="check stage<lead>"` in jQuery Selector.

---

### HTML:

```
<input id="check stage<lead>" type="checkbox" title="Select/Unselect Column" name="chk-stage-column-select" value="" onchange="">
```

---

### Javascript:

```
// escape jquery selectors
    function jQueryEscape(str) {
        if (str)
            return str.replace(/([ #;?%&,.+*<>~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');

        return str;
    }


      var StageName = "<lead>";

  $("[id='check stage" + jQueryEscape(StageName) + "']").prop("checked", true);
```

Equivalent JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vuw43uav/5/

**Note:** I'm using jQuery 1.7 and we can select id with spaces in jQuery. refer this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vuw43uav/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you asked to make it work using jQuery Selector, but you can do it using javascript.

Just select the element using javascript and make it checked.

```
document.getElementById("check stage"+StageName).checked = true;
```

Here is the working fiddle for your 1.7 jquery version.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuw43uav/9/)

In case you want jquery selector, just select the element using javascript and then convert it to jquery selector, I know this is lame but should work fine for you.

```
var y = $(document.getElementById("check stage"+StageName));
y.prop("checked",true);
```

Comment: great answer from a newbie :)

Answer (score 1):

Id attribute must not have any space characters, check this [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home
>   subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not
>   contain any space characters.
>
> There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in
>   particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start
>   with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.

use data-id instead

```
<input data-id="check stage<lead>" type="checkbox" title="Select/Unselect Column" name="chk-stage-column-select" value="" onchange="">

 $("[data-id='check stage" + StageName + "']").prop("checked", true);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/vuw43uav/6/)

Comment: Your source is obsolete. See [the current spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute):  The value must not contain any space characters.

There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.

Comment: Id attribute CAN have space characters.

Comment: @JerryGoyal As per the spec, it shouldn't have. But it may not be supported by current browsers as is. So, I am recommending going with `data-id`

Comment: @gurvinder372 your fiddle is not working for jQuery 1.7. Do you solution for 1.7 version?

Comment: @JerryGoyal 1.7 is not able to use selector with special characters.